# Is there a fast way to gain animosity?

Tags: succubox

I'm going for the motivational sword item in the shop and was wondering if there is a fast way to gain animosity. I have found a decent way but I don't know if it's the best: 40% of employees working, 30% HR and 30% security but is thus the best way to gain it?